# Install Eva Icons individually and keep dynamic colour states

Tags: css, angular, svg, icons, nebular

I would like to use a handful of Eva Icons in my project because the package is quite large. From my understanding we can't install icons individually.
Instead, I've downloaded the svgs and registered the svg pack in the app.component which works:

```html
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private iconsLibrary: NbIconLibraries) {
      this.iconsLibrary.registerSvgPack('eva-icons', {
        'arrow-back': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="arrow-back"><rect width="24" height="24" transform="rotate(90 12 12)" opacity="0"/><path d="M19 11H7.14l3.63-4.36a1 1 0 1 0-1.54-1.28l-5 6a1.19 1.19 0 0 0-.09.15c0 .05 0 .08-.07.13A1 1 0 0 0 4 12a1 1 0 0 0 .07.36c0 .05 0 .08.07.13a1.19 1.19 0 0 0 .09.15l5 6A1 1 0 0 0 10 19a1 1 0 0 0 .64-.23 1 1 0 0 0 .13-1.41L7.14 13H19a1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/></g></g></svg>',
        'book-open-outline': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="book-open"><rect width="24" height="24" transform="rotate(180 12 12)" opacity="0"/><path d="M20.62 4.22a1 1 0 0 0-.84-.2L12 5.77 4.22 4A1 1 0 0 0 3 5v12.2a1 1 0 0 0 .78 1l8 1.8h.44l8-1.8a1 1 0 0 0 .78-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-.38-.78zM5 6.25l6 1.35v10.15L5 16.4zM19 16.4l-6 1.35V7.6l6-1.35z"/></g></g></svg>',
        'camera': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="camera"><rect width="24" height="24" opacity="0"/><path d="M19 7h-3V5.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 3h-3A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 8 5.5V7H5a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v8a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h14a3 3 0 0 0 3-3v-8a3 3 0 0 0-3-3zm-9-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h-4zM20 18a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-8a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1z"/><path d="M12 10.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 0 0 0-3.5-3.5zm0 5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 1.5-1.5 1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5z"/></g></g></svg>',
        'menu-outline': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="menu"><rect width="24" height="24" transform="rotate(180 12 12)" opacity="0"/><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="2" rx=".95" ry=".95"/><rect x="3" y="16" width="18" height="2" rx=".95" ry=".95"/><rect x="3" y="6" width="18" height="2" rx=".95" ry=".95"/></g></g></svg>',
        'edit-outline': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="edit"><rect width="24" height="24" opacity="0"/><path d="M19.4 7.34L16.66 4.6A2 2 0 0 0 14 4.53l-9 9a2 2 0 0 0-.57 1.21L4 18.91a1 1 0 0 0 .29.8A1 1 0 0 0 5 20h.09l4.17-.38a2 2 0 0 0 1.21-.57l9-9a1.92 1.92 0 0 0-.07-2.71zM9.08 17.62l-3 .28.27-3L12 9.32l2.7 2.7zM16 10.68L13.32 8l1.95-2L18 8.73z"/></g></g></svg>',
        
        'teams': '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="people"><rect width="24" height="24" opacity="0"/><path d="M9 11a4 4 0 1 0-4-4 4 4 0 0 0 4 4zm0-6a2 2 0 1 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/><path d="M17 13a3 3 0 1 0-3-3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3zm0-4a1 1 0 1 1-1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1-1z"/><path d="M17 14a5 5 0 0 0-3.06 1.05A7 7 0 0 0 2 20a1 1 0 0 0 2 0 5 5 0 0 1 10 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 6.9 6.9 0 0 0-.86-3.35A3 3 0 0 1 20 19a1 1 0 0 0 2 0 5 5 0 0 0-5-5z"/></g></g></svg>',
  });
  this.iconsLibrary.setDefaultPack('eva-icons');
  }
```

However the nb status is no longer automatically changing the icon colours like before. Please can you advise on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to extract the SVG of **only** the icons you want (from any icon set);
wrap that in a [modern W3C Custom Element/WebComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) that recreates the SVG dynamically,
allowing you to alter presentation any way you want, with attributes, properties or CSS properties.

**https://iconmeister.github.io/ now has 5000+ icons you can pick from**

You then have **No** dependencies, **No** external SVG files

As a test I did all your 6 EVA icons: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/5ct36swL/
(and cleaned up the bloated SVG from EVA icons)

**Usage:**

```html
<style>
  svg-icon {
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    --svg-icon-stroke:darkslategray;
  }
</style>
<div id=toolBar class=icons>
  <svg-icon is="arrow-back" stroke=green></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon is="book-open-outline" fill=red></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon is="camera" opacity=.2 stroke=red></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon is="menu-outline" fill=gold></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon is="edit-outline" rotate=45 fill=blue stroke=white></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon is="teams" scale=.5></svg-icon>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Should work fine in Angular, Vue or Svelte. For React you have to jump through some hoops...
as React only for 71% supports this modern W3C standard (https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/)

`(my)` Related StackOverflow answers: [Custom Elements and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom-Elements-SVG%22&icons)